# Rails 4: How to get first image(child) from an album(parent) for index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, iteration

Album has many images. To display all of my albums on the index page I'd like to have a thumbnail of the first image of the album. Rather than adding an attachment to the album, I was wondering if there was a way I could just pull the first image from that particular album.

This is what I have currently:

**albums/index.html.erb**

```
<% @albums.each do |a| %>
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= link_to image_tag(a.images.first(:thumb)), a %>                     
         <div class="caption">
            <h3><%= a.title %></h3>
               <p><%= a.description %></p>
         </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**models/image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :album

 has_attached_file :photo, 
 styles: { large: "700x700>", medium: "450>", thumb: "200x200>" },
 storage: :s3,
 s3_credentials: Proc.new{ |a| a.instance.s3_credentials }

 validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

 validates_presence_of :title
 validates_presence_of :album_id

 def s3_credentials
    {
      access_key_id:     ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
      secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
      s3_region:         ENV["AWS_REGION"],
      bucket:            ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]
    }
 end
end
```

I'm getting an error "can't convert Symbol into Integer" that points to the line with the `image_tag`

Comment: check if a.images is really an array or a hash!

Comment: try `a.images[0].first(:thumb)`

Comment: @mahatmanich then I get a "**undefined method 'first' for #<Image:0x007fca9a4601d8>**" error when I try `<%= link_to image_tag(a.images[0].first(:thumb)), a %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be `a.images.first.thumb`.

What you're trying to do is call `first` method with `:thumb` argument, but it accepts integer `limit`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/first

EDIT: working code is `a.images.first.photo.url(:thumb)`

Comment: that's gave me `undefined method 'thumb'`. `thumb` is a paperclip method with size parameters.

Comment: Try `a.images.first.url(:thumb)` then

Comment: I tried that, I get 'undefinded method 'url' for <Image...>'. The only thing that hasn't thrown an error is `a.images.first(1)` but instead of giving me a photo it just has a link that describes the different aspects of the image (size, file type, album_id, etc). Do you think I'll need to write a method in the model and use that?

Comment: `a.images.first(1)` is equivalent to `a.images.first`. Could you post the code for `Image` model and its database definition from `schema.rb`?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that the column that holds the attachment for paperclip is `photo`. I've tried to add that to the logic as well but with no luck.

Comment: Then I tried `<%= link_to (image_tag a.images(:photo).url(:thumb).first[0]), a %>` and get "undefined method 'url' for #<Image::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy". Then I tried `<%= link_to (image_tag a.images.photo.url(:thumb).first[0]), a %>` and got the same error but on 'photo' instead of 'url'.

Comment: Try `a.images.first.photo.url(:thumb)`. This means "get album, get images associated with it, get first image, call `url` method on this first image".

Comment: Done! Thanks again!

Comment: That's an upvote. Thanks for that, but you can also "accept" an answer (the answer will have big green tick to the left from the rating).

Comment: Right...sorry I just woke up.